# Elasticity of job-finding rate

Tags: elasticity, search-and-matching

The job-finding rate is

$ f(\theta) = \omega \theta^{1-\eta} $

Then the elasticity wrt to tightness is

$\epsilon= \frac{d f}{d \theta} \frac{\theta}{f} = \frac{d ln(f)}{d ln(\theta)} = \frac{d ln(\omega \theta^{1-\eta})}{d ln(\theta)} = \frac{d ln(\omega)}{d ln(\theta)} + 1-\eta \frac{d ln( \theta)}{d ln(\theta)} =  1-\eta $

Correct?

Comment: I don't see any problem here.